# MS Access SQL Total Hours if greater than 24?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am tracking hours worked per week and am having trouble formatting the duration to show `38:28` instead of `14:28`. In excel it would be `[h]:mm`, but I cannot recreate it in MS Access. Any ideas?

Comment: `[h]:nn` which Access got mad at me for trying, and `h:nn` which gives me the `14:28` (`1/1/1900 14:28:12`) instead of `38:28`.

Comment: What's the datatype, and how are you presenting it? I'm guessing since it's some kind of datetime datatype that it's adding an entire day - are you sure it's 1/1 and not 2/1?

Comment: I have one table that has all of the start and end times and the duration (datetime) for each day. I then have query that adds it together. `SELECT First(DAYS_DURATION.Date) AS [Week], Sum(DAYS_DURATION.Dur) AS Dur
FROM DAYS_DURATION
GROUP BY DatePart("yyyy",[Date])+(DatePart("ww",[Date])/100);`

Comment: There must be something other than a straight sum otherwise you'd have dates far far in the future. Can you edit your question with the full query? How do you get `DAYS_DURATION`?

Comment: It is a sum of the duration not the dates.

Comment: `Dur: [Stop]-[Start]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Time Difference Exceeding 24 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855601/calculating-time-difference-exceeding-24-hours)

Comment: I found out that this actually has been answered before. See my close vote please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```

and then this expression in your query:

```
 Duration: FormatHourMinute([Stop]-[Start])
```